# How to get execution Log of any running applicaion

Tags: log, cpu-load, syslog

When I start running application on Ubuntu 16.04, i have face a problem of CPU usage of 100% for each application for long time. I need to get log of that particular application (its **execution log**) so I can find problem/bug.

Answer (score 2):

To get a log of particular application run in from terminal following way:

```
$ appcommand > out.log 2>error.log
```

Make logs permissions writable, or specify path where it could be written.